# C++ memory allocators and polymorphic types

Tags: c++, stl, standards, allocator

Are memory allocators supposed to be used with polymorphic types?
For example, is the code below correct?

```
class A { ... };
class B { ... };
class C : public A, public B { ... };

std::allocator<C> alloc_c;
auto p_c = alloc_c.allocate(1);

// CASE A: pointer to A and to C point to the same memory address
std::allocator<A> alloc_a(alloc_c);
alloc_a.deallocate((A*)p_c, 1);

// CASE B: pointer to B and to C point to the different memory addresses
std::allocator<B> alloc_b(alloc_c);
alloc_b.deallocate((B*)p_c, 1);
```

Of course, it's either case A or case B, not both.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is UB.

Comment: You are supposed to be rebinding the allocator, not casting the pointer.

Comment: @Columbo What is UB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table 28 in **17.6.3.5** defines `deallocate` this way:

> `a.deallocate(p,n)`: All `n` `T` objects in the area pointed to by `p` shall be destroyed prior to this call. `n` shall match the value passed to `allocate` to obtain this memory. Does not throw exceptions. [ Note:`p` shall not be singular.—end note ]

Per Table 27 right above, `p` is "a value of type `XX::pointer`, obtained by calling `a1.allocate`, where `a1 == a`" (where `XX` is "the type `allocator_traits<X>`", and `X` is "an Allocator class for type `T`"). Further, `a` and `a1` are "values of type `X&`".

In other words, the standard does not envision passing to `deallocate` a pointer allocated by an allocator of a different type. It only specifies what happens when `deallocate` is given a pointer allocated by the same allocator object, or another allocator of the same type that compares equal to this allocator.

At which point, we have

> **1.3.24** undefined behavior
>
> behavior for which this International Standard imposes no requirements
>   [ Note: Undefined behavior may be expected when this International Standard omits any explicit definition of behavior...]